# Getting N related models given M models

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

Given two models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   ...

class Comment(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
   ...
```

Is there a good way to get the last 3 Comments on a set of Posts (i.e. in a single roundtrip to the DB instead of once per post)? A naive implementation to show what I mean:

```
for post in Post.objects.filter(id__in=some_post_ids):
  post.latest_comments = list(Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')[:3])
```

Given `some_post_ids == [1, 2]`, the above will result in 3 queries:

```
[{'sql': 'SELECT "myapp_post"."id" FROM "myapp_post" WHERE "myapp_post"."id" IN (1, 2)', 'time': '0.001'},

{'sql': 'SELECT "myapp_comment"."id", "myapp_comment"."post_id" FROM "myapp_comment" WHERE "myapp_comment"."post_id" = 1  LIMIT 3', 'time': '0.001'},

{'sql': 'SELECT "myapp_comment"."id", "myapp_comment"."post_id" FROM "myapp_comment" WHERE "myapp_comment"."post_id" = 2  LIMIT 3', 'time': '0.001'}]
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080326/django-return-one-filtered-object-per-foreign-key) doesn't give me much hope that this is easy to do through the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

From [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/):

> Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced, using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated (partially or fully) also returns a list.

Your naive implementation is correct and should only make one DB query.  However, don't call `list` on it, I believe that will cause the DB to be hit immediately (although it should still only be a single query). The queryset it already iterable and there really shouldn't be any need to call `list`. More on calling `list` from the same doc page:

> list(). Force evaluation of a QuerySet by calling list() on it. For example:
>   `entry_list = list(Entry.objects.all())`
>   Be warned, though, that this could have a large memory overhead, because Django will load each element of the list into memory. In contrast, iterating over a QuerySet will take advantage of your database to load data and instantiate objects only as you need them.

**UPDATE**:

With your added explanation I believe the following should work (however, it's untested so report back!):

```
post.latest_comments = Comment.objects.filter(post__in=some_post_ids).order_by('-id')
```

Admittedly it doesn't do the limit of 3 comments per post, I'm sure that's possible but can't think of the syntax off the top of my head. Also, remember you can always do a manual query on any Model to get better optimisation, so you can run `Comment.query("Select ...;")`

Given the information [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) on the "select top N from group" problem, if you're `IN` clause will be a small number of posts, it may just be cheaper to either a) do the multiple queries or b) select all comments for the posts then filter in Python.  I'd suggest using a if it's a small number of posts with lots of comments and b if there will be relatively few comments per post.

Comment: I've added so more explanation to the naive implementation and about the solution I'm looking for. Essentially, I am hoping for a single DB query for the entire set of comments, not one per post.

Comment: +1 for the interesting link, it definitely seems like this is not something that is easily solvable with the ORM.

Comment: @bismark cheers, also, just making sure you picked up on the `post__in=some_post_ids` in the update. You don't need the actual model instances, a foreign key field will happy match on models or ids (i.e. the actual values in that db column).